# How to fetch a list of items in a column from Parse cloud using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am a beginner to iOS Swift and presently working with Parse cloud. I need to fetch the contents of a complete column as a list from a class named "Student". I am actually looking to print a list of all the roll numbers from a student class.

My current code is like this:

```
  @IBAction func btn_download(sender: AnyObject) {

        var compQuery = PFQuery(className:"Student")
        compQuery.whereKey("Roll", equalTo:enter_rollnumber.text)

        compQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (Student: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Do something with the found objects
                for competition in Student {
                    println(competition["Name"] as String)
                self.display_name.text = competition["Name"] as String?
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
               println("Error")
            }
        }}
```

Comment: So, what isn't working?  If you want to print roll numbers why are you querying by roll number and printing names?

Comment: this is just what i have done so far. now i need to get all the roll numbers

Comment: i understand that this code doesn't have to do anything with finding roll numbers, but actually i don't know what and how a query is to be written to fetch the rollno's list

Comment: Well, you don't fetch the roll numbers as such.  You fetch the Student objects (like 'rows' in a SQL database) and then access the roll number attribute of those objects.  If you took your current code and removed the `compQuery.whereKey...` then your query will return all students (well, the first 1000) Then in your loop you would use `competition["Roll"]` instead of `competition["Name"]`

Comment: yeah! that worked as i wanted.. thnx Paulw11